# Progress option in fadeout jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, parameters, fadeout

I am trying to use the progress option for the [fadeOut animation in jquery](https://api.jquery.com/fadeout/). I have no idea how to properly implement it though. One of the versions I tried [based on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6573841/jquery-fadeout-timing) is:

```
$(window).on("load", function() {
  var timer = 1000;

  $(".loader-wrapper").fadeOut(timer, progress)

  function progress(progress, progressNb, remaining) {
    console.log(progressNb)
  }
});
```

But I get undefined in the console.

Most of the other answers I found were about starting something after the fadeout animation ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24163586/progress-after-fadeout)), but this is not what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current `fadeOut` function call uses the `.fadeOut( [duration ] [, complete ] )` signature that accepts only duration and complete callback function. But as you need more options you must use the `.fadeOut( options )` signature as follows in order to configure/play with the different options:

```js
$(window).on("load", function() {
  var timer = 1000;

  $(".loader-wrapper").fadeOut({duration: timer, progress: progress})

  function progress(progress, progressNb, remaining) {
    console.log(progressNb)
  }
});
```

Comment: Ohh, got it, thank you very much! I never used options before and I was a little lost on how to implement them. I tried to look for examples, even for other functions, but could not find anything. This is really helping, thanks a lot for your time!